# In Java, how do I store large numbers in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, how do I store numbers in an array, I mean really long numbers like up to 1 trillion so I can access them and print out in words what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) if its really that large. For trillion. [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is enough

Answer (score 11):

1 trillion isn't *that* big - just use a `long`, which can store a number as large as 9223372036854775807 (more than a quintillion):

```
long[] numbers = new long[1000];
```

To store arbitrarily large numbers, use `BigInteger`, but they can be a hassle:

```
BigInteger[] numbers = new BigInteger[1000];
```

Comment: (For some meanings of "arbitrarily large" :-) )