# How to store a large integer in an array

Tags: java

I've imported classes such as `math.BigInteger`; `lang.Long`, and  `java.lang.Math` to no avail.

```
public static void largeNumer()
{    
   long[] num = {2830395970};
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460534/in-java-how-do-i-store-large-numbers-in-an-array

Comment: Did you try `long[] num = {2830395970L};` with an `L` at the end of the number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize a long in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
long[] num = {2830395970L};
```

or

```
long[] num = {2830395970l};
```

And you don't need any additional import.

Comment: Once again, thank you, my friend